# Running an executable file via a .bat file in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, exe

I'm trying to run this **.bat** file via a job in **Task Scheduler**, for some reason the application isn't being run.

Is there something wrong with my syntax? I thought the problem could have been not specifying a window name. I've now added that and it still isn't executing. The code is below (names/ paths have been generalised):

```
ROBOCOPY C:\path\to\file\ Z:\ csvfile.csv /R:2000
START "" \\servername\serverdirectory\serverdirectory2\file.exe
```

When I run this .bat manually it runs correctly. Could it be down to permissions?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running the .bat manually by double clicking on it, for start, to see if it is running?

Comment: Hi - Yes I should've mentioned that. When I manually run the .bat everything runs correctly.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions? On doublecklicking the bat it's being started with your user but the scheduler runs it as system as long as you haven't selected a specific user. Do you have any debug output?

Comment: 'When running the task, use the following user account:' is set to the user I use to double click the .bat file. I've also set to 'Run whether user is logged in or not' to true. And also 'run with highest privileges' ticked on. Hope this is clear!

Comment: What about the log/exit code of the scheduled task?

Comment: 0x0, which I just looked up and it means the task completed. I'll dive further into the logs and see if i can find anything more substantial.

Comment: Adding /log:"c:\somelogfile.txt" as parameter to the ROBOCOPY line might help finding the issue.

Comment: 1. Insert first line `echo "%0% started %date% %time%>>%tmp%\schlog.txt` and so on... 2. What _action_ in Task Scheduler? Imho something like `%comspec% /D /C  "fullpath to your batch\filename.bat"`?

Comment: Instead of `Z:` use `\\ServerName\Share` as mapping a public share to a drive letter is done only for current user account after login.

Comment: Hi Mofi, I've done that and it's copying the CSV to the right place. The .exe still isn't running though. Would running it via a 'CMD' statement work?

Comment: I don't know your environment and what the executable does and which dependences it has.If path to EXE contains anywhere a space character, the file name of the EXE with UNC path must be enclosed in double quotes. It is also possible that execution of applications from a network share are blocked by security guidelines. For example user group "Everyone" has often only the permissions to traverse a network share (read in directory listings), but do not have permissions to read and execute files or even write files and create directories.